# get-wmiobject failing across subnets?

Tags: powershell, subnet

We have two sites linked by a VPN handled by two dedicated Netgear VPN routers.  Each side has a Win2003 domain controller.  Each site can ping all the machines at the other.  The domain controller can successfully do Get-WMIObject queries to the computers ***within*** its own subnet and even a Get-WMIObject query to the other DC in the other subnet.  But neither site can do Get-WMIObject queries to any standard comptuers in the other site.  I receive the error:
The RPC server is unavailable (8x800706BA).  I know RPC is working because it is fine within the subnet.

The VPN routers are set as the gateway for all the machines.

Can someone suggest why my two DCs can RPC each other and each DC can RPC within their own subnets but one cannot RPC the machines in the other subnet?

What I am trying to do is run a set of PowerShell scripts on the main server and retrieve results from the entire domain (both sites).  I could just run the scripts from both servers but that's a pain to maintain everytime we add or change a script.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

RPC is a very complicated protocol when in a firewalled environment.  Just because a DC can talk to its managed computers, doesn't mean an external DC or even external computers can.  So all the computers can ping each other from one domain to another?  You should confirm there are no firewalls at any spots in the communication.  If there are client side firewalls, you should still very them also, as they could have IP-specific rules, just like any firewall can.